# Backand: 'userId' is null after SignUp API call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backand

I am trying to register a new user (Sign Up) with this service module:

```js
(function () {
    angular.module('starter')
    .service('ProfileModel', function ($http, Backand) {
        var service = this,
            baseUrl = '/1/objects/',
            objectName = 'users/';

        function getUrl() {
            return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName;
        }

        function getUrlForId(id) {
            return getUrl() + id;
        }

        service.all = function () {
            return $http.get(getUrl());
        };

        service.fetch = function (id) {
            return $http.get(getUrlForId(id));
        };

        service.create = function (object) {
            return $http.post(getUrl(), object);
        };

        service.update = function (id, object) {
            return $http.put(getUrlForId(id), object);
        };

        service.delete = function (id) {
            return $http.delete(getUrlForId(id));
        };



        service.currentUser = {};

        loadUserDetails();

        function loadUserDetails() {

            return Backand.getUserDetails()
                .then(function (data) {
                    service.currentUser.details = data;
                    if(data !== null)
                        service.currentUser.name = data.username;
                });

        }

        service.getSocialProviders = function () {
            return Backand.getSocialProviders()
        };

        service.socialSignin = function (provider) {
            Backand.setRunSignupAfterErrorInSigninSocial(false); //by default run sign-up if there is no sign in
            return Backand.socialSignin(provider)
                .then(function (response) {
                    loadUserDetails();
                    return response;
                });
        };

        service.socialSignup = function (provider) {
            return Backand.socialSignUp(provider)
                .then(function (response) {
                  loadUserDetails();
                  return response;
                });
        };

        service.signin = function (username, password) {
            return Backand.signin(username, password)
                .then(function (response) {
                    loadUserDetails();
                    return response;
                });
        };

        service.signup = function (firstName, lastName, username, password, parameters) {
            return Backand.signup(firstName, lastName, username, password, password, parameters)
                .then(function (signUpResponse) {
                    return service.signin(username, password)
                        .then(function () {
                            return signUpResponse;
                        });

                });
        };

        service.changePassword = function (oldPassword, newPassword) {
            return Backand.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword)
        };

        service.requestResetPassword = function (username) {
            return Backand.requestResetPassword(username)
        };

        service.resetPassword = function (password, token) {
            return Backand.resetPassword(password, token)
        };

        service.logout = function () {
            Backand.signout().then(function () {
                angular.copy({}, service.currentUser);
            });
        };

    });

}());
```

and

```js
 ProfileModel.signup($scope.user.title, 'last', $scope.user.email, $scope.user.password, parameters)
    .then(
        function(resp){
           console.log(resp); 
        }
   );
```

and I get

```js
Object {access_token: "epn2SW9XHgYj0RBtTv2tGHFmZATrSYqrA79qYnRckBVEaY8is-…m8B7Ko_NTRP-Salr0kh1ppCnOyQKnmzluCpmXOYd7BO7qAdkw", token_type: "bearer", expires_in: 86400, appName: "testthurst", username: "aero47@gmail.com"…}
access_token: "epn2SW9XHgYj0RBtTv2tGHFmZATrSYqrA79qYnRckBVEaY8is-wPWU4sBrnhtNJ8UsqvOeE5_1j_CnTd-HzSfimw_3t4Y9iuOn2N74rb2CCPV0hBFXUOQG1-JLnyqW7kWOc43DRteswmwLqVLRcln6KuHThUeW0wwop2XNiP6NwTsqi-2uokD65QJzoLDWUGEeZkpwZYYwGkXLW7I79INkguVkBauzafOm-vmm8B7Ko_NTRP-Salr0kh1ppCnOyQKnmzluCpmXOYd7BO7qAdkw"
appName: "testthurst"
expires_in: 86400
firstName: "TestUser"
fullName:"TestUser last"
lastName:"last"
regId:
374601
role:"User"
token_type:"bearer"
userId:null
```

By the way the user is appeared in the 'Registered Users' table but not in the 'users' table in the 'Objects' section.

I always get the same result when the 'userId' is null.
Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

When anonymous access switches off or changed into read-only you need to make the call in "Create My App User" action with Admin access.

The solution is to use Admin's permission in the server side action. To add the Admin permission you can use the basic auth Authorization header.

The entire answer is here: [question 36169490](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169490/backand-signup-create-my-app-user-failed-to-perform)

Comment: Just that I mean is  why I was not able to get the valid userId.

Comment: This happens sometimes, not always.